# Calculating image gradient

Tags: java, image, graphics, gradient, derivative

I'll make it short as possible for your convenience.
I'm trying calculate the grey value of each pixel of some image's gradient.

To my knowledge, G(x,y) (the pixel x,y in the gradient image) can be calculated in two ways:

```
1. G(x,y) = sqrt(dx(x,y) * dx(x,y) + dy(x,y) * (dy(x,y))
2. G(x,y) = |dx(x,y)| + |dy(x,y)|
```

I'm trying to understand how the first one results in a value in [0, 255], for example dx(x,y) = 255, dy(x,y) = 255 will result in ~360, which is undefined in grey scale.

Also, how is the second method defined? what does it mean |dx(x,y)| when dx(x,y) belongs to [0, 255], thus positive?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Neither method guarantees that each pixel will be in [0, 255]. If you want all pixels to be in [0, 255] you may need to [normalize](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normalization_(image_processing)) your image after finding the gradient.

The second method is the sum of the absolute difference. Finding an absolute value is faster than taking the square root so method 2 will be faster than method 1.

Comment: Dx(x,y) means the derivative of the pixel in the x direction.